# Getting code error for a simple ChatBot program

Tags: java, chat, chatbot

I'm getting an error at the 2nd class `c.getResponse` 
`The method getResponse(String) is undefined for the type BotTest`
If anyone wants to see what the assignment was heres the pdf:
http://www.cs.stonybrook.edu/~tashbook/fall2013/cse110/project-1.pdf

```
  import java.util.*;

   public class ChatBot {
public String getResponse(String input) {
    int i = 0;
    int found = input.indexOf("you", i);
    if (found == -1)

        return "I'm not important. Let's talk about you instead.";


    int x = longestWord(input).length();
    if (x <= 3) {
        return "Maybe we should move on. Is there anything else you would like to talk about?";
    }

    if (x == 4) {
        return "Tell me more about" + " " + longestWord(input);
    }
    if (x == 5) {
        return "Why do you think" + " " + longestWord(input) + " "
                + "is important?";
    } else if (x > 5) {
        return "Now we are getting somewhere. How does" + " "
                + longestWord(input) + " " + "affect you the most";
    }
    else
        return "I don't understand";
}   


private String longestWord(String input) {
    String word, longestWord = "";
    Scanner turtles = new Scanner(input);
    while (turtles.hasNext()) {
        word = turtles.next();
        if (word.length() > longestWord.length())
            longestWord = word;
    }
    return longestWord;

}

}
```

Second Class to test the code
       import java.util.*;

```
public class BotTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner newturtles = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What would you like to talk about?");
    String input = newturtles.nextLine();
    BotTest c = new BotTest();
    while (!input.toUpperCase().equals("GOODBYE")) {
        System.out.println(c.getResponse(input));
        input = newturtles.nextLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResponse` is defined for `ChatBot` not `BotTest`

```
ChatBot c = new ChatBot();
```

Answer (score 0):

The Class BotTest indeed does NOT have the .getResponse(String) function.  ChatBot does though.